# Compiling Jar file from src and res folder in makefile

Tags: java, makefile, jar

I am trying to compile my java to a jar file using. My directories look like so

```
project/
    src/
        A.java
        B.java
        c/
            C.java
    res/
        img.png
    build/
    makefile
```

how can I take all the java files (src/A.java, src/B.java, src/c/C.java) and put this with the res folder into a jar file in the build folder?

My main function is in A.java

Comment: You could get the names of java files like this `files:=$(shell find ./src -name "*.java")` and, I don't know how it is done to archive files into `.jar` but, you could do `command_to_archive $(files) ...`

Comment: thanks. i know how to compile all the files normally into class files but i dont have a clue when it comes to resources and jar files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put your java files into the res directory. According to [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) you can build your jar file with other folder. Example `jar cmf name-of-jar-file your-manifest-file all-your-class-files res another-directory`